# samplerBuffer in texelFetch()

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures

Frag shader:

```
out vec4 Color;
uniform samplerBuffer sampler;
uniform int index;
void main() 
{
   Color=normalize(texelFetch(sampler,index));

}
```

I am using glTexBuffer() for texturing for all the internal formats given at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexBuffer.xml. Above shader works only for ubyte, ushort  normalised types and float, halffloat unnormalised types. For the rest of the internal formats, it does not apply texture on geometry.

What do I need to change to give me the desired effect?

code

```
GLbyte arr[]={124,5,126};
glGenBuffers(1,&bufferid);

glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,bufferid);

glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,sizeof(arr),arr,GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glGenTextures(1, &buffer_texture);   

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, buffer_texture);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R8I, bufferid);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"sampler"),0);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"index"),0);

glGenBuffers(1,&bufferid1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferid1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices4),vertices4,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

attr_vertex = glGetAttribLocation(shader_data.psId, "a_position");

glVertexAttribPointer(attr_vertex, 2 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_vertex);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"index"),1);

glVertexAttribPointer(attr_vertex, 2 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0,(void *)(32) );

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"index"),2);

glVertexAttribPointer(attr_vertex, 2 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0,(void *)(64) );

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);
```

I have to apply texture using all the internal formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "desired effect" is to have a *single* shader which can work with any format of image data, then there's no way to do it. Or at least, no *simple* way.

You could have three different samplers, bound to three different texture image units, corresponding to the three different possible formats (float, signed-int, unsigned-int). You create 3 different buffer textures (using the same buffer), and bind the appropriate texture to appropriate sampler for the kind of data you want the shader to use. Then you pass a uniform that defines which sampler should be used.

But other than conditional logic like that, no. The sampler's type is used to determine how to interpret the data given to the shader, and it must match with the texture's format.

In general, a shader is designed to expect certain *specific* data, not any old arbitrary thing that the client code wants to hurl at it. A shader that pulls floats out of a texture doesn't care if it's normalized-integers or 16-bit floats, or R11F_G11F_B10F or whatever; the shader just wants floats. It's not appropriate to shove images at a shader that expects floats.

Comment: I tried using isamplerBuffer for GL_8I which is signed byte. But there is no difference in intensity values. I did try using isamplerbuffer for formats having "I" in it and usamplerbuffer for formats having "U" in it, but still output is not as expected.

Comment: @user1737197: What is it that you expect and how does it differ from what you get?

Comment: In above program, i defined GLbyte arr[]={124,5,126}; and in shader "uniform isamplerBuffer sampler" and internal format as GL_R8I. I get 3 quads with same intensity of red color instead of varying  intensity. 
Specs says that this format is not normalized, so i used normalize() function in fragment shader for the color values but still o/p is unexpected.

Comment: @user1737197: How do you normalize it (more importantly, *why* are you normalizing it)? Also, don't put vital information like this in a comment; edit your question and put it in there.

Comment: GL_R8I format does not normalize data, hence i did it manually by Color=normalize(texelFetch(sampler,index)) in fragment shader. I tried  without normalizing also.

Comment: @user1737197: Please stop putting this information in comments. This is not a forum; information needed to answer your question should go into the question. I can't answer your question until your question is complete. And your question is incomplete until you put the *actual* shader and code you're having a problem with into your question.